# get_dummies split character

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

I have data labelled which I need to apply one-hot-encoding: `'786.2'`, `'ICD-9-CM|786.2'`, `'ICD-9-CM'`, `'786.2b|V13.02'`, `'V13.02'`, `'279.12'`, `'ICD-9-CM|V42.81'` is labels. The `|` mean that the document have 2 labels at the same time. So I wrote the code like this:

```
labels = np.asarray(label_docs)

labels = np.array([u'786.2', u'ICD-9-CM|786.2', u'|ICD-9-CM', u'786.2b|V13.02', u'V13.02', u'279.12', u'ICD-9-CM|V42.81|'])

df = pd.DataFrame(labels, columns=['label'])
labels = df['label'].str.get_dummies(sep='|')
```

and the result:

```
279.12  786.2  786.2b  ICD-9-CM  V13.02  V42.81
0       0      1       0         0       0       0
1       0      1       0         1       0       0
2       0      0       0         1       0       0
3       0      0       1         0       1       0
4       0      0       0         0       1       0
5       1      0       0         0       0       0
6       0      0       0         1       0       1
```

However, now I only want 1 label for each document:

`'ICD-9-CM|786.2'` is `'ICD-9-CM'`,

`'ICD-9-CM|V42.81|'` is `'ICD-9-CM'`.

How could I do seperate by `get_dummies` like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and then select first item of list by `str[0]`:

```
print (df.label.str.strip('|').str.split('|').str[0])
0       786.2
1    ICD-9-CM
2    ICD-9-CM
3      786.2b
4      V13.02
5      279.12
6    ICD-9-CM
Name: label, dtype: object

labels = df.label.str.strip('|').str.split('|').str[0].str.get_dummies()
print (labels)
   279.12  786.2  786.2b  ICD-9-CM  V13.02
0       0      1       0         0       0
1       0      0       0         1       0
2       0      0       0         1       0
3       0      0       1         0       0
4       0      0       0         0       1
5       1      0       0         0       0
6       0      0       0         1       0
```

If in row with index `2` need no value, remove `str.strip`:

```
print (df.label.str.split('|').str[0])
0       786.2
1    ICD-9-CM
2            
3      786.2b
4      V13.02
5      279.12
6    ICD-9-CM
Name: label, dtype: object

labels = df.label.str.split('|').str[0].str.get_dummies(sep='|')
print (labels)

   279.12  786.2  786.2b  ICD-9-CM  V13.02
0       0      1       0         0       0
1       0      0       0         1       0
2       0      0       0         0       0
3       0      0       1         0       0
4       0      0       0         0       1
5       1      0       0         0       0
6       0      0       0         1       0
```

Comment: @piRSquared - Thank you.

Comment: Your answer are great